# Reading CSV from text file in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to read CSV from a text file in C. The text file format is

```
1,Bob,bob@gmail.com
2,Daniel,daniel@gmail.com
3,John,john@gmail.com
```

When I run the program, the number displays fine but the name and email are being displayed as garbage. Here is my program...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int number;
    char* name;
    char* email;
} Owner;

Owner owners[100];

int load(char* filename)
{
    char buffer[200];
    char token[50];
    Owner* owner;
    int owners_size = 0;
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");

    while(fgets(buffer, 200, file) != NULL)
    {
        owner = (Owner*)malloc(sizeof(Owner));
        owner->number = atoi(strtok(buffer, ","));
        owner->name = strtok(NULL, ",");
        owner->email = strtok(NULL, ",");
        owners[owners_size++] = *owner;
    }

    fclose(file);
    return owners_size;
}

int main()
{
    int choise, owners_size, index;
    char* owners_filename = "owners2.txt";

    owners_size = load(owners_filename);

    if(owners_size)
    {
        printf("owners size: %d\n\n", owners_size);

        for(index = 0; index < owners_size; index++)
            printf("%d, %s %s\n", owners[index].number, owners[index].name, owners[index].email);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what the reason is. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just stored pointers into a local buffer. When you leave `load()` this `buffer` is gone and not accessible anymore.

You must allocate memory for `name` and `email` before you can copy it into the `Owner` struct.

```
char *tok;
tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
len = strlen(tok);
owner->name = malloc(len + 1);
strcpy(owner->name, tok);
...
```

**[EDIT:** you need to allocate `len+1` bytes so you have space for the terminating `NUL` character.  **-Zack]**

Comment: Note that you've used `len = strlen(tok); owner->name = malloc(len);` which contains a bug and a heap overwrite.  You should be allocating `len + 1` bytes!  `len = strlen(tok) + 1; owner->name = malloc(len);`.  This is why you should use library functions when possible; they're debugged, unlike ad hoc code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Now I see that, that's sufficiently egregious that I'm going to correct it for Olaf.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Zack Thanks for spotting and fixing my embarrassing bugs.

Answer (score 5):

Two problems:

1. You didn't allocate space for the strings in the structure:

   ```
   typedef struct
   {
       int   number;
       char *name;
       char *email;
   } Owner;
   ```

   You need to provide space for those pointers to point at to hold the names.
2. You keep on supplying pointers to the buffer which is reused for each line of input:

   ```
   while(fgets(buffer, 200, file) != NULL)
   {
       owner = (Owner*)malloc(sizeof(Owner));
       owner->number = atoi(strtok(buffer, ","));
       owner->name = strtok(NULL, ",");
       owner->email = strtok(NULL, ",");
       owners[owners_size++] = *owner;
   }
   ```

   The first line gets stored as some pointers into the buffer.  The next line then overwrites the buffer and chops the line up again, trampling all over the original input.

Consider using `strdup()`:

```
while (fgets(buffer, 200, file) != NULL)
{
    owner = (Owner *)malloc(sizeof(Owner));
    owner->number = atoi(strtok(buffer, ","));
    owner->name = strdup(strtok(NULL, ","));
    owner->email = strdup(strtok(NULL, ","));
    owners[owners_size++] = *owner;
}
```

This is slightly dangerous code (I'd not use it in production code) because it doesn't check that `strtok()` found a token when expected (or that `strdup()` was successful).  There again, I wouldn't use [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) in production code either; I'd use POSIX [`strtok_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html) or Microsoft's [`strtok_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx) if they were available, or some alternative technique, probably using `strspn()` and `strcspn()`.  If `strdup()` is not available, you can write your own, with the same or a different name:

```
char *strdup(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *dup = malloc(len);
    if (dup != 0)
        memmove(dup, str, len);  // Or memcpy() - that is safe in this context
    return(dup);
}
```

---

You might note that your code is only suitable for simple CSV files.  If you encountered a line like this (which is legitimate CSV), you'd have problems (with quotes in your values, and mis-splitting because of the comma inside the quoted string):

```
1,"Bob ""The King"" King","Bob King, Itinerant Programmer <bob@gmail.com>"
```

Comment: +1 especially for pointing out that CSV is not actually as simple as it is often made out to be.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer returned by `strtok()` points to an address within the buffer it is parsing, in this case the local variable `buffer`. When `load()` returns the variable it is out of scope (even if it wasn't all instances of `owners` would be pointing the same address). You need to copy the string returned by `strtok()`. You could use `strdup()` if available or use `malloc()` and `strcpy()`.

There is no need to `malloc()` new instances of `Owner` as an array of them already exist (the code as is stands has a memory leak).

Note there is no protection against going beyond the bounds of the `owners` array. If the file has more than `100` entries then the loop will go beyond the bounds of the array. Extend the terminating condition of the `while` to prevent this:

```
while(owners_size < sizeof(owners) / sizeof(owners[0]) &&
      fgets(buffer, 200, file) != NULL)
{
}
```

Comment: Dargh, I missed the memory leak.

Comment: Hmm...me too.  It only goes to reinforce the adage that where there's one bug, there's usually another lurking too, regardless of how many you think you've found.  Well spotted, sir!

Answer (score 1):

You've only got one line buffer.  Every cycle of the loop in `load` clobbers the text from the previous cycle.  And if that wasn't bad enough, the buffer is destroyed when `load` returns.

The quick fix is to change

```
owner->name = strtok(NULL, ",");
owner->email = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

to

```
owner->name = strdup(strtok(NULL, ","));
owner->email = strdup(strtok(NULL, ","));
```

(If you don't have `strdup`, <del>get a real computer</del> it's very simple to write.)

If I were reviewing your code, though, I would ding you for the fixed-size line buffer, the fixed-size owners array, the memory leak, using `atoi` instead of `strtol`, using `strtok` instead of `strsep`, and the absence of quote handling and parse error recovery, and point out that it would be more efficient to allocate each line as a unit and then save pointers into it.